Extract graph with osmnx (ox.graph_from_bbox)
I try to extract a graph for a distance matrix, but idk if my data is wrong or other one.
If a person can help me...
Code :

    df = pd.read_csv('mat1.csv')
    
    def clean_coordinate(value):
        try:
            value = str(value).replace(',', '.')
            return float(value)
        except ValueError:
            return None  
    df['x'] = df['x'].apply(clean_coordinate)
    df['y'] = df['y'].apply(clean_coordinate)

    north = df['x'].max()
    south = df['x'].min()
    east = df['y'].max()
    west = df['y'].min()

    bbox = [north, south, east, west]
    
    graph = ox.graph_from_bbox(*bbox, network_type='drive')


Error :
"FutureWarning: The north, south, east, and west parameters are deprecated and will be removed in the v2.0.0 release. Use the bbox parameter instead. See the OSMnx v2 migration guide: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/1123
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(*bbox, network_type='drive')"

Merci pour votre réponse.
J’essaie et un autre message d’erreur apparaît :
« TypeError : float() doit être une chaîne de caractères ou un nombre réel, pas 'NoneType' »
Cependant, lorsque je demande le type de la variable comme :
print(type(bbox))
print(type(north))
print(type(south))
print(type(east))
print(type(west))

Les fenêtres « Exécuter » renvoient :
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>

Même si je convertis de float64 en float avec ce code :
north1 = north.item()
south1 = south.item()
east1 = east.item()
west1 = west.item()
bbox = [north1, south1, east1, west1]

Le même message d’erreur revient.
Pensez-vous que cette méthode de conversion est mauvaise, ou en est-elle une autre ?
Merci.
Le juge Etienne

(I edited the formatting on the code. In the future, put \``` above and below the code to put it all in one big code block.)

https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-reference.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_bbox can you take out the * splat operator, like: ox.graph_from_bbox(bbox, network_type='drive')

You're reporting a deprecation warning, not an error. Note that your code snippet is not minimal/reproducible (relies on importing an external file), so it's really hard to troubleshoot for you.

See also https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/1193
